# Check common elements between 10 different sets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here I have 18 data frames where each one looks like this

```
       Probe Set ID Call Codes filename
0       AX-11086525         AA   DG2364
1       AX-11086526         BB         
2       AX-11086527         BB         
3       AX-11086528         BB         
4       AX-11086529         AB         
...             ...        ...      ...
587347  AX-11714992         BB         
587348  AX-11714995         AA         
587349  AX-11714996         BB         
587350  AX-11714997         AA         
587351  AX-11714998         AA         

[587352 rows x 3 columns]
```

I am storing all these data frames in a dict called `dfs`,
I want to keep all the rows where the `probe set ID` is common in all the 18 dataframes.
I tried using a set with a bitwise and to find the common items.

```
common_items = set(dfs['df_1']) & set(dfs['df_2']) & set(dfs['df_3'])...
for i in dfs.keys():
    dfs[i] = dfs[i][dfs[i].isin(common_items)]
```

This resulted in a null data frame which I obviously know is incorrect

```
       Probe Set ID Call Codes filename
0               NaN        NaN      NaN
1               NaN        NaN      NaN
2               NaN        NaN      NaN
3               NaN        NaN      NaN
4               NaN        NaN      NaN
...             ...        ...      ...
587347          NaN        NaN      NaN
587348          NaN        NaN      NaN
587349          NaN        NaN      NaN
587350          NaN        NaN      NaN
587351          NaN        NaN      NaN

[587352 rows x 3 columns]
```

Please help

Comment: Can `probe set ID` may appear more than once in the same `df`?

Comment: @Corralien No it is the name of the first column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `set.intersection`

We can use `set.intersection` to find the common ids in `Probe Set ID` column from all the dataframes, then inside a `dict` comprehension iterate over key-dataframe pairs and `query` the `dataframe` to filter the rows with `common_ids`.

```
common_ids = set.intersection(*[set(df['Probe Set ID']) for df in dfs.values()])
dfs = {k: df.query('`Probe Set ID` in @common_ids') for k, df in dfs.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the first method produced this error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/haziq/Documents/dev/python/combine files/cleanfile.py", line 40, in <module>
    common_ids = np.intersect1d(*[df['Probe Set ID'] for df in dfs.values()])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in intersect1d
TypeError: _intersect1d_dispatcher() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 19 were given``` but the second method worked flawlessly thanks @ShubhamSharma

Comment: @maskedpirate Please use the second method of `set.intersection`